# Microsoft Teams team converted from unified group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I was wondering if there was a reliable way to tell if a Microsoft Teams Team has been created from a unified group or created from scratch?

I have been looking at the Graph API to achieve this. It looks like unified groups have a SharePoint Online address but not 100% convinced.

Comment: Teams also have an associated SharePoint TeamSite.

I don't think there's a way to tell the difference. Why do you need to know? That is, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I’m trying to distinguish between a unified group having a Microsoft team from a new Microsoft team created in the team admin area

Comment: Right, but what will you do differently with this knowledge?

Comment: Crest a team from scratch or crest a unified group and convert it

Comment: The Create Team Graph API does not currently support the ability to create the underlying group in one operation. You must create the group using [Create group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) and then add a team to it using [Create team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0).